# How to change ListPreference font colors?

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, listpreference, android-fonts, preferencescreen

I've made the change to the PreferenceScreen background color to blue, but I can't figure out how to change the font color for ListPreference.  I mean the font color on the list.
This font color is black in the blue background.

Is there a way to change this font color?

Thank you very much

Edited: added style.xml

```
<style name="Widget.TextView.ListSeparator" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
<item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
<item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
<item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
<item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
<item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
</style>

<style name="PreferenceListHeader" parent="Widget.TextView.ListSeparator">   
<item name="android:paddingTop">6dp</item>
<item name="android:paddingBottom">6dp</item>
<item name="android:paddingLeft">12dp</item>        
<item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
<item name="android:textSize">24sp</item> 
<item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
<item name="android:background">#cccccc</item>          
</style>

<style name="My_Theme" parent="android:Theme">
<item name="android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle">@style/PreferenceListHeader</item>
<item name="android:background">#001EFF</item>
<item name="android:textColorTertiary">#D95869</item>

<item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FF6347</item>         
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">#00FF45</item>     
<item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>                   
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define theme for your activity in `res/values/styles.xml`. `android:textColorPrimary`, `android:textColorSecondary` and `android:textColorTertiary` are what you are looking for.

```
<style name="PreferencesTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/secondary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorTertiary">@color/tertiary</item>
</style>
```

Then set this theme to activity:

```
<activity
        android:name="your.package.name.YourPrefActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/PreferencesTheme"/>
```

Comment: I had those except
    <item name="android:textColorTertiary">@color/tertiary</item>
I'll add this to my theme and see if it works.  I'll report back when I get home.  Thank you very much Erakitin

Comment: ugg, it is not working :-(  I updated the question with style.xml.   I can change the header colors and everything else except the font color on those ListPreference entry Values/list

Comment: Try to remove `android:textColor` from theme of your pref activity.

Comment: I am sorry that was supposed to be  <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FF6347</item>  I copied them from my app and deleted some of the comments, and I accidently deleted "Primary."  I commented out the Primary and Secondary text colors because they changed the color of my headers and other front colors.  I can change the text color of the titles, headers, summaries, etc.  For some odd reasons, no matter what I have done, it just won't change the Listpreference Entry Values (the list of choice when click on Listpreference) front color.  I just don't understand.